# Update software of a Pico remotely

Tags: update, c, pi-pico, partition, memory

I'm using a raspberry Pi Pico and I'm struggling to find if it's possible to update my script remotely (I cannot use neither SWD or USB). Currently my new firmware (can be .uf2, .bin or .hex file) is stocked in my Pico in the form of an array that I remotely sent, I would like to know if there is any way for me to update the Pico just by rebooting it on the new firmware.

I guess I will have to write my own bootloader but I have no idea where to start and there might be a simplier option (maybe partitionning the flash memory ?).

I'm open to any kind of idea since I don't really know how to start.

Thanks !

Comment: Googled "Pico OTA" (other the air) and got this result. Have not tried it, but its what you are looking for I think.   https://github.com/usedbytes/picowota

Comment: @ChadG Thanks ! I'm gonna have a look at it

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the work of Jakub Zimnol (https://github.com/JZimnol) I have got OTA (Over the Air) Updates for the Pico W firmware working. I've posted a video about this on YouTube: https://youtu.be/Go58qyJpz8Q

My example firmware which switches between Blue and Green releases is at: https://github.com/jondurrant/RPIPicoW-OTA-Exp
The bootloader from Jakub can be found here: https://github.com/JZimnol/pico_fota_bootloader